# Boost asio http request returns partial response

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm following the example client from the boost documentation here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp

What I'm finding is that the response I get is only partial.  The symptom I'm observing is within this piece of code:

```
while (boost::asio::read(socket, response,
          boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error)) {
      std::cout << &response;
}
```

Despite the fact the content-length of my response is `2947795` the above while loop exits when only `261980` of the response has been read i.e not all of it.

Is there anything about this code that would cause it to stop reading and exit the loop before the end?

**Update 1**

If I change the connection of the request to be `Connection: keep-alive` I get the full response body back but it never exits the while loop.  Do I need to write my own check to see if read length `==` content-length and then exit?

**Update 2**

What I'm finding strange is that the while loop always exits after the same amount has been read (i.e `261980`) every single time.

Comment: What is response? Have you modified the code from the example at all?

Comment: The response is just a large portion of text.

Comment: I meant the type of it, which is streambuf. I'm suspicious of the streambuf object use in this example, but am not sure. It's very difficult to manage. Can you provide the URL that you're trying to run this example against so others can test themselves?

Comment: I'm guessing that your response content is either uncompressed text or chunked content.

Comment: It's just uncompressed text.

Comment: Try adding another check after the while(read) loop that checks the size of the streambuf object and prints it out as well. There can be dangling data after the read condition breaks due to an EOF.

Comment: To answer your update question, yes, because keep-alive is instructing the server to sit there waiting for your next request, rather than closing out the connection which would signal EOF. It gets even more complicated when you start dealing with chunked-encoding. My suggestion is to lookup joint http-parser and use its callback and parsing methods if you really want to manually handle http transactions.

Comment: Also, did you try my suggestion? Adding keep-alive isn't actually the problem, the problem (and your update seems to support my theory) is that there is still data that you have not read from the streambuf object before your application exits.

Comment: Yes sorry I did.  If I read the streambuf outside the loop it's empty.

Comment: I'm going to blame your web server or some unknown code modification. I've tested the linked example against multiple uncompressed text files and cannot reproduce this issue. The only difference is that I'm using boost 1.58.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your ongoing help.  Out of interest are you reading a file as big as mine?  I've also implemented a java client using httpcomponents httpclient and it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92169/discussion-between-technik-empire-and-imrichardcole).

Comment: "every single time" - with the same server and request? Also, where's the SSCCE? I can probably name 10 reasons this could happen. Don't make us guess about your code.

Comment: The SSCCE is in the original question, I'm using the example from the boost website.

Comment: It's not. You mean, it's exactly the program linked to? It doesn't include a URL, AFAICT.

Comment: @sehe if you see our linked discussion, it involves a local, custom rolled server.

Comment: So, what can we do to investigate? I'm pretty sure you have your answer [since long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106130/boost-asio-http-request-returns-partial-response#comment54027929_33106130) and only you have the means to debug it, unless you provide us with it. Untill then, this question isn't viable, I guess

Comment: Agreed it's not a viable question, can't be solved as we have one fragment of the puzzle. Pretty sure it's the server code, since I can't reproduce it anywhere else and the issue only happens when keep-alive isn't explicitly declared.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm switching to another rest server to see if the issue lies there.